# FFmpeg randomly stopping during encoding. No error given

Tags: ffmpeg, amd-processor, windows-11

I recently upgraded to Windows 11, just in case that matters, and I went to encode a series of images into a video with FFmpeg like I usually would. For some reason seemingly randomly it just stops. No error is given, the frame that it stops on is random, the amount of time it's encoding for is random, and starting from a different frame doesn't change anything.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -r 59.94 -f image2 -start_number 0 -i "%06d.png" -vcodec libx265 -crf 18 -preset medium -tune grain -pix_fmt yuv420p10le "Encode/S2005E14.mp4"
```

The version of ffmpeg I'm using is the newest git-full version from https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/

The CPU being used to encode it is a Ryzen 3900x.

Log: https://pastebin.com/EnyWs7cL

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: Okay I just added the report.

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -r 59.94 -f image2 -start_number 0 -i "%06d.png" -f null - -report` and share report.

Comment: The file was too large for pastebin so hopefully you'll accept a google drive link to the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rOs7H6Vj8TL2zfCO7r7KWm6T9_AfdgSw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So there doesn't seem to be an issue with the input. Try encoding it with libx264.

Comment: Apparently this was actually caused by my overclock not being stable and I just never noticed until doing something that took 100% of the cpu. Sorry for taking your time. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: This looks like a CPU/Memory problem. Have you checked EVENTVWR?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by an unstable overclock. After reducing the overclock everything worked normally.